# In R: calculate Area Under Precision/Recall Curve (AUPR)?

Tags: r

Suppose I have two matrices: A for Label matrix and B for corresponding predicted probability matrix of A. Now I would like to calculate the the AUPR (Area Under Precision/Recall Curve) according to matrices A and B. For common AUC (Area Under ROC Curve), there are many packages in R, such as ROCR, pROC, can directly calculate the AUC value, but currently, what packages in R can calculate the AUPR? or Can you help give the method the compute the AUPR?
Here is the two example matrics:

```
> pp
        [,1]    [,2]     [,3]    [,4]    [,5]     [,6]    [,7]
[1,] 0.01792 0.00155 -0.00140 0.00522 0.01320  0.22506 0.00454
[2,] 0.05883 0.11256  0.82862 0.12406 0.08298 -0.00392 0.30724
[3,] 0.00743 0.06357  0.14500 0.00213 0.00545  0.03452 0.11189
[4,] 0.02571 0.01460  0.01108 0.00494 0.01246  0.11880 0.05504
[5,] 0.02407 0.00961  0.00720 0.00382 0.01039  0.10974 0.04512

> ll
        D00040 D00066 D00067 D00075 D00088 D00094 D00105
hsa190       0      0      0      0      0      1      0
hsa2099      0      1      1      0      0      0      1
hsa2100      0      0      0      0      0      0      1
hsa2101      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
hsa2103      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
```

`pp` is the predicted probability matrix for the true label `ll` matrix, and `ll` is just the label matrix.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

I would first convert the prediction scores and classes into vectors from matrix.

There is a "PRROC" package that provides the similar function of generating ROC and PRC as "ROCR", and it also gives the AUC of the PRC.

Specifically, I'm using the data `ROCR.simple` from "ROCR" package as an example.

```
library(PRROC)
library(ROCR)
data("ROCR.simple")
scores <- data.frame(ROCR.simple$predictions, ROCR.simple$labels)
pr <- pr.curve(scores.class0=scores[scores$ROCR.simple.labels=="1",]$ROCR.simple.predictions,
             scores.class1=scores[scores$ROCR.simple.labels=="0",]$ROCR.simple.predictions,
             curve=T)
```

Note that here in this function, the "**scores.class0**" needs to be the scores for the **positive** class (which is a little confusing, because personally I consider 0 as negative and 1 as positive). So I switched the order of 0 and 1.

This way, the PR curve and AUC are all saved in the `pr` variable.

```
pr

Precision-recall curve

Area under curve (Integral):
 0.7815038 

Area under curve (Davis & Goadrich):
 0.7814246 

Curve for scores from  0.005422562  to  0.9910964 
( can be plotted with plot(x) )
```

Then, you can plot the PRC with `plot(pr)` or with ggplot:

```
y <- as.data.frame(pr$curve)
ggplot(y, aes(y$V1, y$V2))+geom_path()+ylim(0,1)
```

The resulting curve is the same with the curve made by ROCR package.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you help me with this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39508831/precision-recall-curve-computation-by-prroc-package-in-r)

Comment: @Newbie Sorry, I think to that question, it's simply because the data is too large and you have to wait for the function to obtain the result.

Comment: Can PRROC be used(for PR) for numeric predictions?

Comment: @silk_route11 Yes, I think it can.

Comment: In this example, would `ROCR.simple.labels` refer to the true outcome values or those predicted. For example, the predicted outcome can change if you have a changing threshold but the true outcome values from the test set is always constant.