# Precision-Recall Curve computation by PRROC package in R

Tags: r, auc, precision-recall

My question is relevant to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25020788/in-r-calculate-area-under-precision-recall-curve-aupr) question. I am interested in computing Precision-Recall Curve (PRC) and area under PRC. I found a nice R package **PRROC** to do both tasks. According to [package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/PRROC/PRROC.pdf) description (page 5) for function **pr.curve**, you have to give 2 parameters. 1) the classification scores of datapoints belonging to positive class **only** 2) the classification scores of datapoints belonging to negative class **only** (See manual page 7). The example they provide is:

```
# create artificial scores as random numbers
x <- rnorm( 1000 );
y <- rnorm( 1000, -1 );
# compute PR curve
pr <- pr.curve( x, y, curve = TRUE );
```

My problem is I have 14000 datapoints in positive class and 2560595 datapoints in negative class and for such data it is already being 1 day and still I haven't got results. For simplicity purpose you can try an extension of already given example.

```
# create artificial scores as random numbers
x <- rnorm( 14000 );
y <- rnorm( 2560595, -1 );
# compute PR curve
pr <- pr.curve( x, y, curve = TRUE );
```

Comment: Can you clarify what your question is.

Comment: @jonno-bourne Question is for my dataset PRROC package's pr.curve function is not working. Even the example they provided does not work if you increase the datapoints.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try `AUPRC()` from `PerfMeas` package

**Edited**

This [precrec](https://takayasaito.github.io/precrec/) package seems to be better. It is compatible with ggplot2 and implemented with C++. For benchmark result please check [this paper](https://www.google.co.th/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=18&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj6qdKhh47WAhXIjLwKHW2sCNg4ChAWCFUwBw&url=http%3A%2F%2Fbioinformatics.oxfordjournals.org%2Fcontent%2Fearly%2F2016%2F09%2F17%2Fbioinformatics.btw570.full.pdf&usg=AFQjCNGjxSdW8mf0XQWMnB-nbHFn_Eoh_A)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/94027/285661) for instructions how to write *better* "link-based" answers. Thanks!